# PHP - failed to open stream : redirection limit reached

Tags: php, http, request

My codes is here

```php
<?php  echo (file_get_contents("http://123.com/video/latest.php")); ?>
```

Here is the error How can solve this

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://123.com/video/latest.php): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/123/public_html/index.php on line 340

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `facebook`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code, which won't follow the redirects automatically:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => false
        )
    )
);

$html = file_get_contents('YOUR_URL', false, $context);
```

The other problem is that the URL you are trying to get content from returns a 404 error.

Comment: The url is this http://www.spacenepal.com/video/latest.php its works fine but where i have puted it show blank.